# Mortal threat in Star Trek TOS: "Wink of an Eye"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In the episode "Wink of an Eye" Kirk once again finds himself face to face with a hideous space alien.

[image: Monster from outer space]

Much like the matriarch of the society featured in the prior episode who wanted to make Dr. McCoy her husband, this alien apparently took over the Enterprise with the intention of reproducing with Kirk, and making him her King.

She stated that this was necessary for the survival of her race, because the men of her society no longer reproduce with women.

[image]

Kirk angrily argues with her and seems to imply that having sex with her is equivalent to death:

> **Alien Queen**: We'll be kind to you, you won't be harmed. I do like you... Captain, we have the right to survive.
>
> **Kirk**: Not by killing others!

Killing others? What is he talking about?

The only person who died was an Ensign who died from accelerated aging after being injured, but that's apparently a situation that only occurred if a person was injured shortly average being "accelerated" to the speed of this hyper-fast race.

Comment: You get a +1 purely for the "hideous space alien".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the link between prior injury and death by hyper-acceleration that you have posited is not necessarily correct.  Some further dialogue:

> **DEELA:** Damaged.
>
> **KIRK:** Damaged, they age incredibly fast, as though accelerated living.
>
> **DEELA:** Burns them out.
>
> **KIRK:** Burns them out. Compton was burned out. The device attached to the life-support system produces an extreme, numbing cold. It is my belief that they are turning the Enterprise into a gigantic deep-freeze for purposes only the Scalosians know.
>
> **DEELA:** Quite correct.

Later in the conversation:

> **DEELA:** ***Whenever a spaceship came by, we'd send our calls for help. But accelerating them to our level burned them out.*** Don't you see, Captain? Do I have to go into every detail? We are going to take you down with us. Perhaps one or two others of your crew. We have to. We'll be kind to you. I wouldn't hurt you, certainly. I do like you.

Being "burned out" seems to be the unavoidable result of hyper-acceleration, by Deela's own admission despite her promise to do no harm.

Comment: Well the Ensign wouldn't have died if it were not for his injury. She did mention to her male subjects that she intended to keep Kirk as her lover for "a long time". But perhaps you're right and I underestimated the degree to which the acceleration affected humans. I'll mark this as the solution.

Comment: @y0gapants : Yes, I think Deela is deluded that the acceleration can be done safely despite a great deal of evidence to the contrary.  She believes it is enough that she *intends* to do no harm.

Comment: Also I believe that even if Kirk did live his lifespan, it would be an instant to those on the ship. He would, for all intents and purposes be dead. Similar to the hyper speed planet in Voyager??